# Derivative of a self-referencing function

Tags: calculus

I have a question about how to take the derivative of a function that is a function of itself. My function is a wave function that is a function of its own speed like so:

```
v=sin[wt-wx/(B+v)]
```

If I want to take the time derivative of v, how would I go about doing so?

Thanks

Comment: Your calculus textbook should have a section on "implicit differentiation".

Comment: Thanks! Its been a while since I've needed to do implicit differentiation!

Answer (score 0):

This is known as implicit differentiation.  You basically take the derivative of both sides (a little more happens behind the scenes,  but bear with me).  In your case I'm not sure what variable $v$ is a function of...  Say we have $v(t)$. 
$$v(t) = \sin[wt-wx/(B+v)]$$
$$\implies v' = \cos(wt-wx/(B+v)) \frac{d}{dt} \frac{wt-wx}{B+v}$$

$$=\cos(wt-wx/(B+v)) \frac{w(B+v) - (wt-wx)v'}{(B+v)^2}$$